# $\sum_{n=1}^{+ \infty} a_{n} \frac{1-e^{-n^{2}t}}{n} = 0$ implies $a_{n} = 0$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Say that for the coefficients $a_{n} \in \mathbb{R}$, we have that
$$ \sum_{n=1}^{+ \infty} a_{n} \frac{1-e^{-n^{2}t}}{n} = 0$$
for every $t > 0$. Does this imply that $a_{n} = 0$ for every $n \in \mathbb{N}$?

Comment: Why do you differentiate twice the letter $e$ in the word co$\underline{e}$fficient )

Comment: Sorry, it's something you have to do in my language. I've edited it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. First, it is clear that $a_n/n$ is bounded, since the series converges. So $\sum a_n e^{-n^2t}/n$ is absolutely convergent. Moreover, it vanishes in the limit as $t\to\infty$, so we get $\sum a_n/n=0$ (this sum might be only conditionally convergent). Therefore we can subtract out that part, and we now have
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{a_n e^{-n^2t}}n=0$$ for all $t>0$. Put $z=e^{-t}$. Then this is
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{a_n z^{n^2}}n=0$$ for all $z\in(0,1)$.
Then this holds by analytic continuation for all complex $z$ with $|z|<1$, and the general theory of power series now implies that $a_n=0$ for all $n$.

Comment: I can't see that "clear" in your first line.

Comment: @Timbuc the $n$th term in the original series is asymptotically equal to $a_n/n$ as $n\to\infty$.

Comment: I don't really need to do analytic continuation, though. The series will be convergent when $|z|<1$, and since the sum is identically zero for $z\in(0,1)$, all derivatives vanish at $z=0$. I'll let the answer stand, since that is how I first thought of it.

Comment: I see it now. Thank you. For some reason I thought $\;e^{-n^2t}\longrightarrow 1\;$ .

Comment: @Harald Hanche-Olsen I don't understand the part where you say : Substracting, we get ..., Could you explain it a little bit please?

Comment: How do you get $\sum a_n/n=0$?

Comment: @themaker Right; I had forgotten a limit argument as I had to go somewhere and was in a hurry. I have added it now.

Comment: @JuliánAguirre See the previous comment.